# window.print() from Observable .subscribe() method

Tags: angular, printing, rxjs

I am curious why I'm not able to display a print dialog from inside of a `.subscribe()`, but I am able to do it if I convert the `Observable` to a promise and call `window.print()` from inside of the promise's `.then()` method.  Can somebody explain the difference?  When I try to do it from `.subscribe()`, it just simply does not display - no error message.

```
// Does not work
timer(1000)
  .pipe(take(10)) // 10 second delay
  .subscribe(() => window.print());

// Works
timer(1000)
  .pipe(take(10)) // 10 second delay
  .toPromise()
  .then(() => window.print());
```

Comment: can u please post the code also?

Comment: probabily because the .subscribe () is async and promise no

Comment: works for me, can you post your code for us to see what's happening?

Comment: I edited the question and added sample code.

Comment: It appears that my question may have been prematurely posted (and poorly derived).  In isolated testing, I see that the basic principal DOES work as expected.  So perhaps the problem is related to something specific with my production app.  It may be noteworthy that in my real app, my timer subscription is inside of a service subscription.

Comment: At this point, it IS working in production as expected (without converting to a promise).  Thanks to all that chimed in and my apologies for failing to properly test before posting the question.  Interestingly, a window.close() that was also previously not working is working now as well.  In both cases all I did was pull the code out of the subscribe() and into separate functions that are called from within the subscribe() - which should be functionally identical.  So unfortunately, I'm not certain what actually fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproduce window.print() in subscribe. It worked

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.ts.output.subscribe(v => {

      if(v) {
        window.print();
        this.name = v.name;
      }
    }) 
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-print-in-subscribe